# Upload file to azure blob storage

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-addin, file-upload, remote-blob-storage, azure

I have a SharePoint app with a custom action. With this custom action I want to upload the selected file in the SharePoint document library to a container in the azure blob storage.

How can I upload the file to azure?

I've tried sending the url of the file to a page on the host web and put the file in a stream using the url but I get an error 401 unauthorized.

Answer (score 0):

Once You have the file stream, you can use the below code to upload file to blob storage.

```
string azureConnString = "YourAzureStorageConnStringName";
    CloudBlobClient blobClient;
    CloudStorageAccount storageAccount;
    CloudBlobContainer container;
    CloudBlockBlob blockBlob;
    public bool AddFileToBlob(System.IO.Stream stream, string fileName, string containerName)
    {
        byte[] bytesarr =  GetByteFromStream(stream); //Convert the stream to byte array

        using (MemoryStream memoryStrem = new MemoryStream(bytesarr))
        {

            // Retrieve storage account from connection string.
            storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(
            CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting(azureConnString));

            // Create the blob client.
            blobClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();

            // Retrieve reference to a previously created container.
            container = blobClient.GetContainerReference(containerName);
            container.CreateIfNotExists();

            // Retrieve reference to a blob named "myblob".
            blockBlob = container.GetBlockBlobReference(fileName);
            if (!blockBlob.Exists())
                blockBlob.UploadFromStream(memoryStrem);


            return true;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Maybe I didn't formulate my question right. I know about that part. The problem is getting the file from sharepoint into a stream.

Comment: Can you please post your code that is giving you unauthorized error? Are you using a high trust provider hosted app ?